# UIImage scale propotionally

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a UIImageView. and i am setting a UIImage to this UIImageView with content mode as UIContentModeScaleAspectFit. Can i know the scale in which the UIImage is resizing when using UIContentModeScaleAspectFit.

Comment: could u please explain more abt ur situation ?

Comment: UIImageView *view=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,768,500)]; UIImage *im; And assume size of the image be 1024 * 700. When i set this image as the image of UIImageview it will resize the image proportionally as i set the content mode of UIImageView as UIContentModeScaleAspectFit. I want to know the scale Factor in which it is scaling or the width or height of the image.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but not automatically :)

The scale will be something like

```
CGFloat widthScale = imageView.bounds.size.width / image.size.width;
CGFloat heightScale = imageView.bounds.size.height / image.size.height;
```

You will have to use the correct one depending on if the image has fitted vertically or horizontally ;)

Comment: If the image size is 1240 * 1754, both the width and height will reduce. Is there any method to find this reduced width and height. If i take UIImageView.image i will get a image which has the size of the UIImageView. Is there any method to get the resized image from the UIImageView.